# Port Blocking of OSC Messages But Firewall is Off

Tags: macos, catalina, firewall

In my computer I am trying to receive Open Sound Control from a server running internally from an application, the address is '127.0.0.1:57110'. The problem I have is that the OSC seems to be blocked and I cannot receive any messages from the server. My firewall is turned off and I am not running any other limitation based on any other rulesets (afaik). Is there a way to find out if something else is blocking the messages to be received in my application or something to use where I unblock the specific port?

Comment: Where is this server running?  On the same machine?

Comment: Yes, intended communication is internal on the same computer. BTW, I am running the pfctl also to disable anything that might be in the middle, and as I said App Firewall is turned off. I can confirm other ports are fine as much as I can tell..

Comment: `pf`, by default excludes loopback from rules, so it shouldn’t matter.  Are you sure messages are being sent and if do, to the correct port?  How did you test?

Comment: I am running this in SuperCollider (server <> client application for sound synthesis). Which when I am trying to boot with this line `b = Server(\two5, NetAddr("localhost", 57110), s.options.copy.maxLogins_(2), 1);` It returns: "SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 44100.000000, driver's block size = 512
SuperCollider 3 server ready." But the GUI of the Server is Idle, it seems the status reply message from the Server is not received back in the client (see this image [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cney336qt73193k/Screenshot%202020-05-31%2010.23.08.png?dl=0).

Comment: Try using the IP address and not the localhost address - it may be configured to only listen on that interface.

Comment: I am using this, NetAddr("192.168.1.100", 57110) I just edited to make it clearer. That is my computers IP as noted in System Preferences > Network

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “I’m using the NetAddr...”. Your question states you’re using 172.0.0.  What are you using where?  How is this software configured and where is the server sending the messages?  Post that info to the **question**, please; not in comments